# Ether is not transferring in this code from one account to other.?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >0.5.0 < 0.9.0;

contract TestPay {

```
function payEther()payable public{
    //  user will pay to contract
}

function transferEther(address payable _to,uint amt) payable public{
    _to.transfer(amt);
}
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question and show repro steps how you're invoking the function. Especially the argument values, and ETH values of the transactions.

Comment: I am using remix ide

Comment: Ok. So what do you pass as `_to`, and `amt`? Do you set any `value` in the "Deploy & Run Transactions" tab? Apart from deploying contract, is `transferEther()` the only function you're executing (once) - or did you execute `payEther()` as well? If so, what `value` did you pass?

Comment: actually in the parameter itself I want to pass the reciever address and and the amount. But its not working, when I use msg.value in _to.transfer(msg.value) it is working